# I need to know how to change the magento customer address book drop down to radio buttons

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, javascript, css

I have a requirement in magento checkout page customer address input dropdown to  radio buttons please help me is it possible to change dropdown to radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Frontend forms are not auto generated on the frontend like they are on the backend - this means you will need to build the radio button functionality yourself.  Turn on template hints under `system->configuration->developer` then select a store scope from the drop down at the top of the left column and once done under `debug` you will see `template path hints`.  Change this to have template paths displayed on the frontend.  Identify the correct template on the page in question and edit.

Comment: why i had post this question is i am new to mageno. can u provide any tutorial please.